# What is the right way to use jquery validate and $.ajax together?

Tags: jquery, ajax

What is the right way to use jquery validate and $.ajax together? I am trying to save the data via Ajax once the form passes validation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#np-submit').click(function() {

        if($("#newsletter-subscription").validate()) {

            var name = $("input#fullname").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var interest = $("select#interest").val();
            var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&interest=' + interest;
            //alert (dataString);return false;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../save_address.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    alert("Contact Form Submitted!");
                }
            });
        });

    $("#newsletter-subscription").validate({
        rules: {
            fullname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            interest: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            fullname: "Please enter a your first name.",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
            interest: "Please select your area of interest."
        }
    });
    });
});
```

Comment: and what's the problem with this code? the validation fails? the ajax call doesn't run? the server response is not arriving?

Comment: Instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {` it would be better to use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. Otherwise using `jQuery` right at the beginning of the statement serves no purpose.

Comment: the only problem I can guess is here: email: { required: true, email: true, }, email value has an extra comma (`,`), try to remove it

Comment: I think you missed his point; he asked what is the best way to combine validator and ajax of a form.

Comment: I can't clearly understand from the question if he's doing this task successfully or not, so I think that this issue could be generate a javascript error

Comment: it may generate an error on IE, but on chrome it won't

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a callback to the validator `submitHandler` property, and initiate an AJAX request.

Here is an example of providing a callback to the [submitHandler](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate), and initiating an AJAX submit of the form:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({   
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(); 
    }
});
```

`.ajaxSubmit` is not a core functionality of jQuery. It is provided by the [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

You can read about `submitHandler` and the rest of the options `.validator` objects may receive at the [jQuery validator plugin manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate).